# free PDF reader with zoom

Tags: linux, open-source, pdf-viewer

I'm working with largish PDFs (e.g. 17523x2383 dots @ 72dpi), where i need to zoom out (to see the overall picture and to navigate) and to zoom in (to read labels on the nodes).

The PDFs are simple graphs (generated from `gv`) containing mostly text, text-boxes and lines, andthe occasional thumbnail image. The only thing special about them is there size.

I don't think, that the graphics are complicated to render, e.g. using the [xdot.py](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py) program to visualize the `gv` graphs (before they are rendered into a PDF) is blindingly fast, so I can scroll and zoom arbitrarily in realtime.

Unfortunately, it seems that all all *PDF readers* (that I have tried) have problems with such formats.

Afaict, I require the the following features:
- fast renderer (so it can be used interactively)
- zoom in to `>100%` (ideally unlimited)
- zoom out to `<2%` (ideally unlimited)
- when zooming, keep focus
- minimal dependences (i'm running *xfce4*; i'd rather not pull in half of *kde* or *gnome* just to display a PDF)
- free software (FLOSS)

These are the readers that i've tried:

- `evince`: renders the complete page nicely (at a zoom-level `4.93%`), but refuses to zoom in to more than `41.47%`)
- `vprerex`: only has 6 fixed zoom-levels between `100%` and `400%`, thus not allowing me navigate.
- `mupdf`: limits zoom-out to `25%`; more importantly, I haven't found a way to keep a given point focused, when using the scroll-wheel to zoom-in, thus making it impossible to navigate the page.
- `firefox built-in PDF reader`: while it limits zoom-out with the mouse-wheel to `25%`, it also allows for a `zoom to page-width` which allows for an overall view of the image, and then to zoom in (until `1000%`) ata select spot. unfortunately, rendering at any size where the font is big enough to be readable (e.g. `70%` and above) makes the image very *blury*
- `atril` limits zoom-in to `50%`
- `qpdfviewer` loses focus when zooming; takes ages to render a new zoom level
- `Adobe PDF reader` is not free/libre/open-source

So my question is: is there a free (as in *Free/Libre/OpenSource Software*) PDF reader that allows for arbitrary and interactive zoom in/zoom out?

Comment: Any dependencies OK? Then you could take a look at Okular (KDE). I'm currently not at my machine, so I cannot check for "arbitrary zoom" – but zoom it does :)

Comment: `okular` does indeed handle the zoom nicely, though KDE is a bummer: it doesn't exactly match the *minimal dependencies* requirement; apart from that it is probably the best viewer for this specific task.

Comment: So shall I expand it as answer, despite of "violating" the *minimal dependencies?* I'm curious for other answers myself: if there's anything coming close to *Okular*, my chances to get rid of all the KDE libs on my next install would dramatically increase :)

Comment: have u tried foxit? be careful when installing it not to add any bells and whistles, just the vanilla viewer.

Comment: @Izzy I ended up using *okular* for my tasks; so if you expand your comment to an answer, i will *accept* it.

Comment: Done. If you want, I can cross-check with other PDF viewers I've meanwhile installed (I've abandoned all KDE dependencies when I had to do a fresh install on my machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>As requested, converting my comments to an answer:</sup>

If you can live with all the KDE dependencies it requires (e.g. because you're using KDE anyway),¹ you can use **[Okular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular)** for this. It handles zooming fine, and beside PDF also supports a bunch of other formats (e.g. EPUB). *Okular* is the default document viewer used by the KDE project. It meets most of your requirements:

- **fast renderer:** to my experience, yes.
- **zoom in to >100% (ideally unlimited) - zoom out to <2% (ideally unlimited):** didn't check the percentage's lower limit, but > 100% I can confirm
- **when zooming, keep focus:** at least when scrolling with the mouse, AFAIR
- **minimal dependences:** unfortunately requires a bunch of KDE libs
- **free software (FLOSS):** yes.

I've meanwhile abandoned all KDE dependencies and mostly use qPDFviewer (which you already ruled out as it loses focus on zooming), so I can no longer cross-check – but my requirements differ from yours.

---

¹ <sub>Though your question points out the opposite, in your comments you've acknoledged it would be OK :)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is `xpdf`. Though it zooms to only 4x size, you can select a rectangular area and *zoom to selection* of any size. At the zoom level you can pan in any direction to view the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

[PDF Studio Viewer](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/), which is a free PDF Reader for Linux, can zoom from 10% to 6400%. It also has a loupe tool that can be used to look at fine details in the file at high zoom levels.

Disclosure: I am a developer at Qoppa Software.

Comment: it seems that this is only "free as in beer", as opposed to  *free (as in Free/Libre/OpenSource Software)* (as requested), which I meant to read "free as in speech"